# VBA sorting a collection by value

Tags: vba, collections, bubble-sort, heapsort

I have the VBA collection below

[image]

[image]

I want to sort by the value such that the collection will end up with the highest double value in the highest index position (i.e. "e" with value 14 is in first index, "c" with value 10 is second, etc). How is this possible?

```
Public Function SortCollection(ByVal c As Collection) As Collection
    Dim n As Long: n = c.Count

    If n = 0 Then
        Set SortCollection = New Collection
    Exit Function

    ReDim Index(0 To n - 1) As Long ' allocate index array
    Dim i As Long, m As Long

    For i = 0 To n - 1: Index(i) = i + 1: Next ' fill index array

    For i = n \ 2 - 1 To 0 Step -1 ' generate ordered heap
        Heapify c, Index, i, n
    Next

    For m = n To 2 Step -1 ' sort the index array
        Exchange Index, 0, m - 1 ' move highest element to top
        Heapify c, Index, 0, m - 1
    Next

    Dim c2 As New Collection
    For i = 0 To n - 1 ' fill output collection
         c2.Add c.item(Index(i))
    Next

    Set SortCollection = c2

   End Function

Private Sub Heapify(ByVal c As Collection, Index() As Long, ByVal i1 As Long, ByVal n As Long)
   ' Heap order rule: a[i] >= a[2*i+1] and a[i] >= a[2*i+2]
   Dim nDiv2 As Long: nDiv2 = n \ 2
   Dim i As Long: i = i1
   Do While i < nDiv2
      Dim k As Long: k = 2 * i + 1
      If k + 1 < n Then
         If c.item(Index(k)) < c.item(Index(k + 1)) Then k = k + 1
         End If
      If c.item(Index(i)) >= c.item(Index(k)) Then Exit Do
      Exchange Index, i, k
      i = k
      Loop
   End Sub

Private Sub Exchange(Index() As Long, ByVal i As Long, ByVal j As Long)
   Dim Temp As Long: Temp = Index(i)
   Index(i) = Index(j)
   Index(j) = Temp
   End Sub
```

Comment: can you post your script.

Comment: Not really, I'm about 1500 lines in and all the data is coming from a variety of angles. What more information do you need?

Comment: can you add the part where you are creating the collection and trying to get the highest number.

Comment: added an attempt at a heapsort algorithm

Comment: you could copy the key/value pairs into a hidden worksheet and do the sort there, then copy back

Comment: Good idea. I was trying to keep away from using hidden worksheets, but it might work best for now. Cheers.

Comment: If you use a Dictionary object instead of a Collection and you can sort by value as shown [here](http://xl-central.com/sort-a-dictionary-by-item.html).

Comment: @Domenic, after some modification, this works well. Please create an answer for it to be accepted. Cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per Domenic in comment and he hasn't answered.

"If you use a Dictionary object instead of a Collection and you can sort by value as shown [here](http://xl-central.com/sort-a-dictionary-by-item.html). – Domenic Aug 30 at 22:29 "

This works now.